# Safety of "more or less" cured pancetta?

Tags: food-safety, pork, curing

I bought a non-dried pancetta and wanted to prepare a pasta recipe that involved cured pancetta. Since it was the weekend and I wouldn't be able to go to the market to get one, I heavily seasoned it with salt, pepper and paprika, and put it wide open in the fridge (no covers, just sitting on a plate). It is been there for about two days now (I understand that it is far, far from actually being cured), the consistency and color has changed (it is much more dry than before).

Since before this I was preparing pasta with non dried pancetta, I'm already convinced this is a step forward so I just wanted to try it out.

But my concern now is with the safety of eating it, as I have heard about things like botulism and so on.

I intend to cook the pancetta before eating it obviously, but I heard that some toxins/bacteria can survive the cooking process.

Is it safe to eat? For information, the non-dried pancetta was frozen. I defroze it, then heavily seasoned it, then stored it in the fridge. I used no special ingredients other than the seasonings.

Comment: It's probably no worse than using raw meat and cooking it before using/eating it

Comment: Are you asking if the introduction of salt and spices on the outside of the meat could cause foodborne illness?

Comment: @GdD No. It is more the fact that I defroze food that was previously frozen and left it on the fridge uncovered for two days. Usually, after opening a packet of meat, I freeze the rest instead of leaving it open on the fridge. In this case I did precisely the contrary.

Comment: A couple of questions/comments: It's technically not "pancetta" unless it is cured. Also, while true pancetta can be eaten raw, it is usually cooked.  Do you mean to say that you bought a piece of pork belly? Finally, it sounds like it was kept in the refrigerator, so that's safe... I am not really sure what you are asking.

Comment: Hi, we have stopped answering questions on whether a specific food handled in a specific way is safe, since there are myriads of variations, and food safety works differently. There are a few basic rules, and you have to apply them literally to your piece of food. We have summarized them under the tag wiki https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info, with further links on the bottom. Since I can't close as a duplicate to a tag wiki, I chose a target which seems to apply to your case as far as I can tell - it is better to read the wiki itself for you to decide which rule applies.

Comment: @rumtscho, I don't understand why you make this a duplicate of that question, the food was not left at room temperature, it was refrigerated.

Comment: @GdD In the comment OP said it was left out, so I picked that one. We could use https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer too, or instead. I'll add it.

Comment: non dried pancetta just sounds like bacon